# Induction to prove that something is not true?

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

This is maybe a very basic question, but I have never seen it done before. Can you use induction to prove that something is not true? In particular if something does not hold in dimension n=1, can I use induction to prove that it does not hold with higher dimension?

Comment: Yes, $P$ is false $\iff$ $\lnot P$ is true, and  $\ \lnot P(n)\Rightarrow\lnot P(n\!+\!1)$  $\,\iff\,$ $P(n\!+\!1)\Rightarrow P(n),\,$ or, in words,
falsity ascends iff truth descends

Answer (score 2):

One example is showing that ${\mathbb R}^n$ is not a union of countably many proper subspaces. For this you can assume the contrary and intersect with a hyperplane and get that ${\mathbb R}^{n-1}$ is a union of countably many proper subspaces. The base case $n = 2$ is easy because there are uncountably many angles through the origin.